# Run Maven Enforcer Plugin rule on command line

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I would like to enforce the requireReleaseDeps rule of the Maven Enforcer Plugin on a Maven project without any POM configuration simply as a command line call.

According to the docs I should be able to just pass in the rules parameter like so

```
mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=requireReleaseDeps
```

or maybe this should work

```
mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireReleaseDeps
```

However both of these calls result in

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (default-cli) on project hel
lo-world: The parameters 'rules' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce are missing or in
valid -> [Help 1]
```

Anybody know if this usage scenario actually works somehow or do I have to dive into debugging the plugin at this stage to figure this out?

Comment: I looked at the [docs for the enforce goal](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html), and there is no user property set for the rules parameter, which in my experience means you can't define the property from the command line with -D.

Comment: Can you show us your pom?

Comment: The pom has nothing in it that is of interest. It should work on ANY project.

Comment: @ManfredMoser it was a while ago but.. did you find/apply any solution?

Comment: No ... At some stage I will have to create a patch towards the plugin. Just have to find the time to do so..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the version 3.0.0-M3 of the plugin and newer release the enforcer goal now supports the rules parameter and command line execution without config in the pom. See more at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html#commandLineRules

<s>Unfortunately there is currently no such functionality but there is already a [JIRA Issue for that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-142).</s>

Comment: pity the JIRA ticket is there since 2012 and still no action

Comment: What about offering a patch for this?

Comment: seems like this feature will come. At least code has been commited in version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT 2 days ago. Well done Maven devs !

Comment: @FrancoisMarot Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It works with the `3.0.0-M3` version:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce -Drules=requireReleaseDeps
```

Answer (score 6):

It is available from 3.0.0. The Jira issue from accepted answer got resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-142

```
mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=alwaysPass,alwaysFail
```

Comment: Yeah, but still waiting for a release. Maybe @khmarbaise knows when that will happen..

Comment: It seems to have been released now: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/examples/check-specific-rule-via-cli.html

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me using Atlassian's fork of the plugin:
`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-atlassian-m01:enforce -Drules=...`

I had to declare their plugin repository:

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    ....
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-3rdparty</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Hope this helps.