# Maven build should fail if the 'buildVersion' argument doesn't exist or has empty value

Tags: java, maven, build

The main `pom` file receives the version value as a maven command-line argument.

What I want to achieve is to prevent the build from executing if the argument is either non-existing in the command (not passed), or if it has empty string value, something like `-DbuildVersion=` or `-DbuildVersion=""`.

The reason is that the generated JARs should not end up without the version number, or worse - with the dummy value set in the `buildVersion` property.

=================
Solution: For anyone having the similar need - use Maven Enforcer Plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Comment: Usually each pom file has a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` which will result in the appropriate artifacts...So I don't see the problem?Why do you need the `buildVersion`? How could you produce artifacts without a version number? Can you show your pom file which makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest the Maven Enforcer plugin (http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/), but it seems that it's not possible yet -> [Run Maven Enforcer Plugin rule on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157668/run-maven-enforcer-plugin-rule-on-command-line/22158383#22158383).
Wouldn't be fine for you to wrap the build process in a scrip that would make that validation for you?

Comment: Actually, I've already stumbled upon the Maven Enforcer Plugin and it indeed worked. The link you provided seems obsolete now.