# Add parameters to Maven Enforcer Rules called from the command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, maven-enforcer-plugin

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389998/927493, one can now call the Maven enforcer plugin from the command line.

This works well, but unfortunately I haven't understood yet whether I can set rule parameters through the command line. An example would be `version` in the `RequireMavenVersion` rule.

Comment: It seems that setting parameters via command line is not supported.

Comment: FYI, I find the question interesting and [documented the corresponding problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-142?focusedCommentId=17041565&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17041565) in the Jira issue because I consider it a bug. There is not even an automated test for rules with parameters, thus this was never detected. Apart from setting a parameter via CLI, it does not even work if same parameter is defined in your POM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't. I'm actually not that happy with the current implementation because of these expectations. The first usecase was a simple, parameterless rule. Of course we could predict the next questions.

Let's first explain how "complex" plugin configuration works. Take a look at the following example:

```
<rules>
  <requireMavenVersion>
    <version/>
  </requireMavenVersion>
</rules>
```

Here requireMavenVersion is the lowercase classname in the same package as the EnforceMojo(or `enforce` goal), version is a setter on this class. What you see is nothing more than a Pojo. The only requirement here is that RequireMavenVersion implements the EnforcerRule interface, so Maven can call its `execute` method  see:

```
 @Parameter
 private EnforcerRule[] rules;
```

If you want to call a rule from commandline, the plugin simple tries to rename the rule to a full qualified classname make a new instance of it. Next its execute method will be called.

The request for this feature was to enforce rules without touching the project. This should be solved as a Maven Extension, which fits much better to that usecase.

But in conclusion: no you can't.

**UPDATE** As of Maven Enforcer 3.0.0 there's a [Maven Enforcer Extension](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-extension/usage.html) which gives you an extra way to define enforcer rules.